# How to do dependency management in Visual Studio/MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, dependency-management

There have been many posts on this topic, but I have yet to find the "real" solution.

How does one manage their dependency tree (both compile time and runtime) using MSBuild project files (i.e. Visual Studio project files via project and file references)?

It is well known that project references from child projects will not be copied to an application bin directory if there is no compile time reference, even if there is a runtime dependency, and even if copy-local=true. Hence, any loosely coupled component will not be copied over.

The hack to solve this problem is to include the dependency in the parent project with copy-local=true. However, this basically destroys your dependency tree as you no longer know where the dependency is and ultimately, as your app grows and morphs, you end up with a version of DLL hell. Your parent project ends up with 10s to 100s of dlls, most of which are runtime dependencies of dlls in child projects.

Another hack is to write a custom targets file and call it from every project file: http://blog.alexyakunin.com/2009/09/making-msbuild-visual-studio-to.html. But surely there is a better option. This is such a bread and butter thing. Java devs never have to deal with such trivial issues.

From what I can gather, the Microsoft way to solve this problem is to register every dependency in the GAC for every dev, test and production machine. But this is stupid and annoying. I won't bother giving this option and educated rebuttal.

Avoiding the GAC option, how could one use MSBuild to manage a dependency tree that includes  runtime only dependencies? How does Microsoft do it? Surely they don't run custom targets files like the one in the link above.

I hope someone from an enterprise .NET background can step up and offer some real advice on this. Otherwise I'm just going to have to rewrite all my build scripts in NAnt (*shudder*).

Thanks All.

UPDATE

In response to some comments, the following is a practical example of the issue from my current project.

The app is a Web Application project that exposes a suite of WCF services. It has an external domain DLL containing the external service classes and an internal domain DLL containing internal service POCOs, domain objects and DAOs. There is a separate integration DLL containing interfaces (DTOs) for all the internal domain classes that allows us to completely decouple the external and internal domains. The whole thing is wired up with Spring.net. I hope this is clear, let me know if you need more clarification.

My current build process is to use MSBuild to generate a deployment package for the web application (in TFS Build). So while the whole solution is built initially, only the output from the web application gets packaged. Therefore, the Web Application is treated as the dependency root and I expect that any loosely coupled child references should get copied over on build if they are set to 'copy-always=true'.

So the Web Application contains a reference to the external domain DLL which contains a reference to the internal domain DLL which contains many references to 3rd party libraries and various indirect and loosely coupled dependencies required by the 3rd party libraries.

The problem occurs when there is a 3rd party dependency in the internal domain DLL e.g. oracle.dataaccess which is required by NHibernate at runtime. Even when I set 'copy-always=true' on these DLLs, they do not get copied to the Web App package. The only way I can include them in the package is to add these DLLs to the Web App's references. I don't want to do this because I no longer have a meaningful dependency tree.

I hope this makes the issue clearer. Please let me know if anything is unclear. It's hard to describe this sort of stuff.

If anyone is also having a similar issue, please speak up and share your experience.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that adding them to the GAC will be inefficient, but I was just curious how NAnt will help you more in this case? Also how in Java development this situations would be handled? I'm trying to more clues so that I can give you better answer... Thank you

Comment: I think he wants something like maven in Java. In fact I'm looking for something similar too. http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: In reflection, I think that NAnt would cause more problems. I'll update the original post with a specific example of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really want to give you a better answer but unfortunately you didn't put enough information about your solution/projects and your dependencies, so I will try to give you several ideas and I hope one of them works.

1. The easiest thing to do as you said is  to set up a separate folder with all of your dependencies and create target file that will copy them to your bin folder. If you have dependencies that are not changing frequently that might work. If another team from your company is building them and they change frequently, this approach is not good.
2. Another simple approach - if you're referencing your dependencies from your solution only you can change the build path, so that they build directly into the bin folder of your main project. This way you don't have to reference them directly.
3. Use NuGet. You have a separate team producing loosely coupled dependencies it may make a sense to set up local NuGet repository and use it for that http://juristr.com/blog/2012/04/using-nuget-to-distribute-our-company/

I hope that helps.